# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` in a `DataGrid` in a `WPF` project set like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Master" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding MasterId}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Id}" DisplayMemberPath="Id" ItemsSource="{Binding Masters}" />
```

but when I run the project the column display only blank values and the combobox in edit mode does the same thing.

The DataGrid is set like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="ReadersGrid"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Readers}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

And the UserControl like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SmartAccess.Tabs.ReadersTab"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SmartAccess.Tabs"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" DataContext="{StaticResource ReadersListViewModel}">
```

and the other columns, only text, work fine.

The ViewModel has these properties

```
public ObservableCollection<ReaderViewModel> Readers { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<ReaderViewModel> Masters => Readers.Concat(new List<ReaderViewModel> { new ReaderViewModel { Id = -1 } }).OrderBy(t => t.Id);
```

And the collection viewmodel has these properties

```
public long Id { get; set; }
public long MasterId { get; set; }
```

I'm displaying `Id` only for test, a description property will be added in future.

Why the ComboBoxColumn is not working?

Comment: I don't see a question.  Recommend you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on how to ask this kind of question.  And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: There are probably binding issues, look at the output windows of your running project, it should tell you which properties are not found, and where it is looking for them.

Comment: @omerts the error is this: `System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Masters; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=24534150); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')` but I don't understand

Comment: `Masters` is not a property of `ReaderViewModel` which is cell's DataContext. You need a RelativeSource binding for column's ItemsSource.

Comment: @icebat thanks, but I don't understand how to get the `Masters` property from the VM. I tried this but it's not working: `<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Master" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding MasterId}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Id}" DisplayMemberPath="Id" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Masters, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ReadersTab}}}" />`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is caused by `DataGridColumns`: indeed they [do not belong to the visual tree](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vinsibal/2009/04/07/5-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid/), so you cannot bind their properties to your `DataContext`.

You can find [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) a solution based on a kind of freezable "DataContext proxy", since `Freezable` objects can inherit the `DataContext` even when they are not in the visual tree.

Now if you put this proxy in the `DataGrid`'s resources, it can be bound the the `DataGrid`'s `DataContext` and can be retrieve by using the `StaticResource` keyword.

So you XAML will become:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Master" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding MasterId}"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Id}" DisplayMemberPath="Id"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Masters, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
```

Where `proxy` is the name of your resource.

I hope it can help you.

**EDIT**

I update my answer with the code copied from this [link](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) (because of @icebat's comment). This is the `BindingProxy` class:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Then in the XAML you need to add:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: I don't understand completely the example, but it seems to work as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @IlVic, it's great!