# DataGridComboBoxColumn Binding Converter not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Referring to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808855/wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn-not-working):

I've this DataGridComboBoxColumn:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Master" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding MasterId}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Id}" DisplayMemberPath="Id" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Masters, Converter={converters:SimpleComboItemConverter}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
```

I created this IValueConverter for the runtime error raised when trying to save the value to the row.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(SimpleComboItem<>))]
public class SimpleComboItemConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public static SimpleComboItemConverter converter;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (null == converter)
        {
            converter = new SimpleComboItemConverter();
        }
        return converter;
    }
}
```

but when debugging inside it the Convert method has IEnumerable objects in value and not a `string` and a `SimpleComboBoxItem<>`

The SimpleComboBoxItem class it really simple and the ComboBox in the column displays the right values:

```
public class SimpleComboItem<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Data.Masters` is an IEnumerable and passed to the `value` argument. So what is your expectation?

Comment: You're right, I set the converter in the wrong place, in the SelectedItemBinding will work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the xaml, you're mapping an Id as an Item. You have to use the SelectedValueBinding instead of SelectedItemBinding.