# 2nd Binding property of ComboBox pointing to its first property binding object

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagridtemplatecolumn

I tried to solve this problem for 1 week, But I couldn't! I was searching and reading many pages, including these:

[(www.thomaslevesque.com) [WPF] HOW TO BIND TO DATA WHEN THE DATACONTEXT IS NOT INHERITED](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)

[(stackoverflow) How do I use WPF bindings with RelativeSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource)

[(stackoverflow) WPF - Binding error in DataGridComboboxColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123825/wpf-binding-error-in-datagridcomboboxcolumn)

[(stackoverflow) WPF Error 40 BindingExpression path error: property not found on 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173869/wpf-error-40-bindingexpression-path-error-property-not-found-on-object)

**What am I trying to do!?**

I have a domain class and a table in SQL LocalDb by name of TermType (you can see its code below) with 5 properties:

- TermTypeId
- TypeName
- Description
- StartDate
- EndDate

My app reads `TermType` table and It supposed to show them inside a `DataGrid` like this:

[image]

But it do not show Start/End date for each term type because It failed in binding `StartDate`/`EndDate` properties in right way! and Also I get this error message at `Output` window (not as exception):

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'StartDate' property not found on 'object' ''MonthName' (HashCode=38847270)'. BindingExpression:Path=StartDate; DataItem='MonthName' (HashCode=38847270); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedIndex' (type 'Int32')
```

Before I say more! Please check my `UserControl` xaml file that related to this window:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PresentationWPF.View.UserPanels.UserControlTermTypeCrud"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PresentationWPF.View.UserPanels"
             xmlns:userPanels="clr-namespace:PresentationWPF.ViewModel.Client.UserPanels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:PresentationWPF.View.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             Background="DarkSlateGray">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <userPanels:TermTypeCrudViewModel x:Key="TermTypeCrudViewModel"/>
        <converters:IndexToMonthConverter x:Key="IndexToMonthConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource TermTypeCrudViewModel}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TermTypes}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <!--
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <userPanels:BindingProxy x:Key="MyProxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            -->
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Term Name" Binding="{Binding TypeName}" Width="120"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="*"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date Range" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Start: "/>
                                    <ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                                               Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxMonthNamesStyle}"
                                               SelectedIndex="{Binding StartDate,
                                                                Converter={StaticResource IndexToMonthConverter}}"
                                    />

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="End: "/>
                                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                                              Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxMonthNamesStyle}"
                                              SelectedIndex="{Binding EndDate, 
                                                                Converter={StaticResource IndexToMonthConverter}}"
                                    />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I know the problem at `ComboBox` is in its second property binding `SelectedIndex` that it try to find out '`StartDate`' property inside of `MonthName` object, instead of `TermTypes` from `DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TermTypes}"`. But I do not know how to do it!? Even I tried to use `RelativeSource`inside of `SelectedIndex` property binding, But I may not use it correctly!!!

If in Visual Studio 2017 I hover mouse over `StartDate` in `ComboBox`, It show this message too:

Cannot resolve property 'StartDate' in data context of type 'PresentationWPF.View.UserPanels.TermTypeCrudViewModel'

I even try to use `Freezable class` (as suggested in first link I put at begging) and as you can see I commented the line of `DataGrid.Resources`, but even if I try to use it at `ComboBox`, `SelectedIndex` still `Data` property of `BindingProxy` object do not point to `TermTypes`.

***NOTE:*** I try to insert month names directly inside `ComboBox` in xaml (by using `ComboBoxItem`) and omit `Style`binding like below code and It worked, *But still I like to know how to fix the code while I am using `Style`binding in that way*:

```
<ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
           SelectedIndex="{Binding StartDate,
                            Converter={StaticResource IndexToMonthConverter}}"
>
    <ComboBoxItem>January</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>February</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>March</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>April</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>May</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>June</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>July</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>August</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>September</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>October</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>November</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>December</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

**I will appreciated to tell me how to solve this problem!?**

**Did I use MVVM and UnitOfWork in the right way!?**

**Any better suggestion to replace MonthName class or ComboBox Style in App.xaml!?**

Or any other issues that may you see in my codes!? **Thanks so much in Advanced.**

In case you need to see/know about my other related classes and ... here they are:

**TermType Class:**

```
namespace Core.BusinessLayer.Domain
{
    public partial class TermType
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public TermType()
        {
            Terms = new HashSet<Term>();
        }

        public int TermTypeId { get; set; }

        public string TypeName { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Term> Terms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**(Model) TermTypeCrudService  Class:**

```
namespace PresentationWPF.Model
{
    public class TermTypeCrudService : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new AgsContext());
        public bool IsDbDirty = false;

        public IEnumerable<TermType> GetTermTypes() => _unitOfWork.TermTypes.GetAll();

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (IsDbDirty)
                _unitOfWork.Complete();
            _unitOfWork.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**(ViewModel) TermTypeCrudViewModel Class:**

```
namespace PresentationWPF.ViewModel.Client.UserPanels
{
    public class TermTypeCrudViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly TermTypeCrudService _termTypeCrudService = new TermTypeCrudService();

        private ObservableCollection<TermType> _termTypes;
        public ObservableCollection<TermType> TermTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return _termTypes;
            }
            set
            {
                _termTypes = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public TermTypeCrudViewModel()
        {
               TermTypes = new ObservableCollection<TermType>(_termTypeCrudService.GetTermTypes());
        }
        public void Dispose() => _termTypeCrudService.Dispose();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**(View - Code behind) class:**

```
namespace PresentationWPF.View.UserPanels
{
    public partial class UserControlTermTypeCrud : IUserPanelNavigation
    {
        private readonly TermTypeCrudViewModel _termTypeCrudViewModel;

        public UserControlTermTypeCrud()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _termTypeCrudViewModel = FindResource("TermTypeCrudViewModel") as TermTypeCrudViewModel;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<TermType> TermTypes
        {
            get => (ObservableCollection<TermType>)_termTypeCrudViewModel.TermTypes;
            set => _termTypeCrudViewModel.TermTypes = value;
        }


        public event EventHandler OnNavigateEvent;
        public string Title => "Term Types";
        public UserControl NavigateToPanel { get; set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _termTypeCrudViewModel.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml file:**

```
<Application x:Class="PresentationWPF.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PresentationWPF"
             xmlns:userPanels="clr-namespace:PresentationWPF.ViewModel.Client.UserPanels"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--
            Create Month names list to use in ComboBox
        -->
        <userPanels:MonthName x:Key="MonthName" />
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="ComboBoxMonthNamesStyle">
            <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{StaticResource MonthName}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MonthNamesCollection}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MonthName class:**

```
namespace PresentationWPF.ViewModel.Client.UserPanels
{
    public class MonthName 
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _monthNamesCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public ObservableCollection<string> MonthNamesCollection
        {
            get => _monthNamesCollection;
            set => _monthNamesCollection = value;
        }

        public MonthName()
        {
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("January"); //      31 days
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("February"); //     28 days in a common year and 29 days in leap years
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("March"); //        31 days
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("April"); //        30 days
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("May"); //          31 days
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("June"); //         30 days
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("July"); //         31 days
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("August"); //       31 days
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("September"); //    30 days
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("October"); //      31 days
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("November"); //     30 days
            MonthNamesCollection.Add("December"); //     31 days
        }
    }
}
```

**Converter class that I used in `ComboBox` `SelectedIndex`:**

```
namespace PresentationWPF.View.Converters
{
    public class IndexToMonthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        private DateTime _dateTime;

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Convert Month in 'value(DateTime)' ==> Index 0 to 11
            if (value is DateTime b)
            {
                _dateTime = b;
                return b.Month - 1;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Convert 'value(int)' 0 to 11 ==> Month number
            if(value is int b)
                return new DateTime(1,b + 1,1);

            return _dateTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Binding StarDate` is a typo. It should be `Binding StartDate`.

Comment: @Clemens Oppsss! Thanks! I guess it happen in my many try and failed cases!  Now it work in case if I omit `Style` property and use ComboBoxItem. But I like to know how I can fix it If still I want to use Style in that way.

Comment: `{Binding StartDate, ...}` expects a StartDate property in the current DataContext. Your ComboBox Style sets DataContext to an instance of MonthName, which does not have that property. Solution: do not set DataContext in a Style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set the DataContext property in a Combobox Style. Doing so breaks any DataContext-based Binding like `{Binding StartDate}`.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="ComboBoxMonthNamesStyle">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
            Value="{Binding MonthNamesCollection, Source={StaticResource MonthName}}"/>
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks soooooo much! It is alive!!!!! :D (Working I mean ;))  I was doing everything for past 7 or 9 days in anywhere in my codes except in App.xaml !!!! Could you kindly tell me what do you think about another 2 questions I asked!? Specially my next plan will be to do this: "When user select Start date May, at End date ComboBox should show June to December"

Comment: As a note, if StartDate and EndDate are only months, using `DateTime?` as property type seems odd. Just use a string, or probably an enum. You could then directly bind the ComboBox's SelectedItem property, without the Converter.